# Typescript decorator typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to set the typing of a decorator in a way that will allow type inference in a scenario where that decorator function is used as a parameter to another function.

```
console.clear();

function myDecorator<T>(someMemberName?: keyof T) {
  return (target: any) => { //A: as soon as I change this from any to T - the decorators break
    console.log(someMemberName)
    return target;
  }
}

function describe<T>(c: T, decorator: any) {
  decorator(c);
}



// test that it works
@myDecorator()
@myDecorator<myClass>("a")
class myClass {
  a = 'some string';
  b='one more thing'
}
describe(myClass, myDecorator<myClass>("a"));
describe(myClass, myDecorator("a")); // B: I want intelisense to work here as well
describe(myClass, myDecorator("c")); //C: I want this to fail on compile time
```

I need all of this code to work (except item C:)

When I change `A:` from any to T - all the decorators break.

When I try to set the `myDecorator` function return type - to something that uses `T` it breaks.

Would love a typescript hero to help me

See playground at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC4DMBXMYAFwEtwACAWwE8ARWUVZMkVAHgBUA+dFFqwAsrFoAjWKgByyYQH4AXNQDWseiALUemagG9c1aqlhkiqMNXRk0AczMrkYenoC8fA9QD03gIJOENRQNMhBAJLUwAAWzg7UZNEUQQSoILTUzvQJIDrUALQJ0bDUACYsnOycQRKmyKpGxlHgUHDw0CB2gumi4lKy8rCYjcam5pYJ9mZ4xgC+uPOEJORUVuUQwKgUUrwCwCo8ADRlFWwcqE4ueobG5axVGMA4C-j4vgmwEGRF7NQU3wB3TiqCC4AACDGY93OWHBkNODy4DAAwtAwhABAAiZCY4ZIdF0eiogk3TLUNzUADkQhKXy2YDslJm1Akbkp4BKtE4JUSFAZlJe60221g6BRaIgEGO8OhnCRRIlGPQ2NxzyFWykYoV6OlTARMJVmBwPm81AAQipIgDnN8+WRYNBkrBIDzckDUKpqMVTJkggCHdBcOqRVriZLdVDKgbgKrsCbkZbqNawN9eUEONQCMgKNBqDRQLQAA45nkUYRAA

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm following what you're doing, especially the line `@myDecorator()` by itself which seems to be broken.  I can fix the typing like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBREkN) but there's not a good way to get *inference* if you call `@myDecorator("a"); class Foo {a = 123}`, the compiler will be unhappy.  Maybe if you change the typing to [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAQEQm) it will do what you want, but I'm really not clear on the use case.  Let me know which if either of these solutions you want to see and I'll write up an answer. If neither, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks so much for your answer, it almost resolved my issue, but the case with the `@myDecorator()` is also a requirement that I need to fix.
This decorator is used in my code sometimes without any arguments (so sending it the generic class type is redundant) and sometimes with an argument - and in that case, I specify the generic parameter (I would prefer it to be inferred, but couldn't get that to work)
Note that in my project, the parameter is an object that some of it's members require the generic parameter

It'll be great if you can help me resolve both these cases.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `@myDecorator()` requirement *is*, though.  Specifying generic class is redundant even for `@myDecorator("a")`.  If you want some kind of inference I'd recommend my second method like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXj58m), otherwise my first version might work by defaulting the class type to the loose `any` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wORnyW).   Which one of these, if any, do you want me to write up as an answer?  If I'm still not understanding what you're doing, then please help.

Comment: You are getting close to the answer - but not there yet.

The problem I'm facing is that I have a decorator that only in some of the cases requires a generic definition - so I need both cases to work, `@myDecorator()` and `@myDecorator<myClass>("a")`.
In the case of `@myDecorator("a")` it doesn't infer the type, so I have to add the `myClass` to it's generic type.
That's ok - I can live with specifying the class when using decorators this way, but I wanted to avoid that later

Comment: I think we may be at an impasse, unfortunately.  I don't understand how either of [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXj58m) or [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wORnyW) fails to work for your needs.  In order to proceed I would need specific code examples of use cases that don't work the way you expect when used with my solutions.  I can't figure it out by "almost" or "getting closer", or any similar [parlor game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_thimble) method.  If you can't provide such a code example then I'm probably unable to help further.  Good luck!